Creating a table using html. How to make the cells not move out?
I need to make a table like this in HTML.

Tried to do a normal layout, but any time I try to fix something, the table moves away.....
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
       }
    td,
    th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

I tried to do it this way, but it's all moving away..

I've also tried this, but I can't merge the three cells that are crossed out, when I try to merge them, the table moves off to the side again.


What is the use-case? As far as I see it it most likely will not be to display tabular data. As such it would be more suitable for a CSS Grid.

As tacoshy hinted at, HTML tables should only be used for marking up semantically tabular content. If you're just trying to arrange your page in a grid layout, do not use tables and instead use CSS grid, flexbox, or other CSS-based layout techniques.

Your "fourth" row is not needed since you only need three rows (and your last cells have a height of 2 and 3). Also, your second cell in the second row does not have a rowspan set, even though they have all the same height. You can adjust the table like this:


    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
       }
    td,
    th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="height: 3em">A</td>
            <td colspan="3">B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" style="height: 2em">C</td>
            <td rowspan="3">D</td>
            <td rowspan="3">E</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">F</td>
            <td rowspan="2">G</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



The height: 3em styles are only for display clarity, otherwise you couldn't really see how the different cells with the different rowspan values arrange to each other. Remove them as necessary.
